# Is Safari not correctly images using srcset pictures?

Tags: html, webkit, srcset

I'm looking at [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/) for reference

The code I'm trying to get to work looks like this

```
<figure>
        <picture>
                <source srcset="images/specto1@1x.png 1x, images/specto1@2x.png 2x">
                <source srcset="images/specto1.png">
                <img src="images/specto1-old.png" alt"Spectrogram of hiss event at the South Pole">
        </picture>
        <figcaption>Spectrogram of hiss event at the South Pole</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[The demo for loading different images](http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/) using scrset does not seem to work with safari 9 however it works fine in chrome.  I was under the impression that safari and iOS has now implemented scrset attribute since safari 9 and iOS safari 8.

At the moment safari 9 is loading specto1-old.png while chrome is loading specter1@1.png

Can someone explain why the demo works in chrome but not safari?

EDIT: Idk How i butchered the tittle so badly.  "Is safari not correctly displaying images using the srcset and pictures tag?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`srcset` on `img` should work in Safari but `picture` doesn't work yet (only in beta at the moment).

Comment: webkit is killing me.  Is there a good site you can search html tags that will give you compatibility for the browser?